# Compactness and Lipschitz functions

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness, lipschitz-functions

I am very stumped by this question:

> Suppose (K, d) is a compact metric space. Let f be any function, f: K $\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, not necessarily continuous. Prove that for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a finite M such that:
>
> |$f(u) - f(v)$| $\leq$ Md($u,v$) + $\epsilon$
>
> for all u,v $\in$ K

Couple things:

1. Does $\epsilon$ matter here? If the above holds for every $\epsilon$, then |$f(u) - f(v)$| $\leq$ Md($u,v$). Then it becomes a matter of proving that f is Lipschitz.
2. My first intuition was applying the mean value theorem, but unfortunately f is not continuous. Is there another way to approach the problem (i.e. using sequential compactness)?

Comment: Your claim would in particular imply that $f$ is bounded. This is not the case in general (because you do **NOT** assume that $f$ is continuous). Hence, your claim is false.

Comment: I feel like we must be missing some information from the question.

Comment: @Pelto, I forgot to mention that it holds for all u,v $\in$ K

Comment: Consider $K = [0,1]$, and $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 &, x = 0 \\ \frac{1}{x} &, x > 0.\end{cases}$$ If you don't impose any restrictions on $f$, it's wrong. Continuity is necessary.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer, thank you for the counterexample. I guess some information is indeed missing. I will try to clarify this immediately.

Comment: Continuity is necessary and sufficient, by the way. Regarding your point 2, you cannot assume that $K$ is such that some form of mean value theorem even makes sense for functions defined on $K$.

Comment: As a hint, when you have the continuity requirement confirmed, $A(\delta) = \{ (x,y)\in K\times K : d(x,y) \geqslant \delta\}$ is compact for every $\delta > 0$.